# Updating the environment variable and path variable

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

Previously I set variable `UIMA_HOME` in " `/etc/environment`

Now I opened this file again and changes the path, so looks like

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$UIMA_HOME/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386"
UIMA_HOME="/root/Desktop/karim/software/UIMA/apache-uima"
```

But when check `$UIMA_HOME` it gives:

```
bash: /root/Desktop/karim/software/UIMA/UIMA_SDK_1.4.5: Is a directory
```

how come?

There is one instruction: Append `UIMA_HOME/bin` to your PATH

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/game:UIMA_HOME/bin"
```

is this correct, or should it be

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/game:$UIMA_HOME/bin"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding **environment** variable, you have to do

```
sudo source /etc/environment
```

It can **commit** your **environment** variables.

Answer (score 1):

> But when check `$UIMA_HOME` it gives:
>
> ```
> bash: /root/Desktop/karim/software/UIMA/UIMA_SDK_1.4.5: Is a directory
> ```
>
> how come?

Did you restart your shell? `/etc/environment` is read when you log in; if you just continue working, the changes won't have taken place.

> There is one instruction: Append `UIMA_HOME/bin` to your PATH
>
> ```
>  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/game:UIMA_HOME/bin"
> ```
>
> is this correct, or should it be
>
> ```
> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/game:$UIMA_HOME/bin"
> ```

The latter. The first one would look for the subdirectory `UIMA_HOME` wherever you happen to be, which most likely does not exist. `$UIMA_HOME` would be replaced by the variable contents.

Comment: yes, I restarted the shell, but still $UIMA_HOME gives wrong path

Comment: Err, it's actually not shell, sorry. Shell reads `/etc/profile`. `/etc/environment` is read by PAM, so on `ssh`, `su` etc.